# Call Delegate methods from another class

Tags: c#, objective-c

I am having trouble figuring out how to program delegate method calls across classes in C#. I am coming from the world of Objective-C, which may be confusing me. In Objective-C, I can assign a delegate object inside a child class, to be the parent class (I.e., `childViewcontroller.delegate = self;`). Then I can to fire a method in the delegate class by using:

```
if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(methodName:)]) {
   [delegate methodName:parametersgohere];
}
```

However, I can't figure out how to do this in C#. I've read a bit about C# delegates in general (for example, [here](http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/explaining-delegates-in-c.aspx)), but I'm still stuck.

Are there any examples that explain this?

**Here is my scenario in full:** 
I have classA which instantiates an instance of classB. ClassB fires a method (which call a web service), and upon response, I'd like to fire a method in classA.

Any 'Hello World' types of tutorials out there that might explain the very basics of this?

Comment: Be reminded that C#/.NET delegates are an entirely different kind of thing from Objective-C/Cocoa delegates.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Yeah, I think that's where I am going wrong. But I'd still like to figure out how to replicate the above scenario. :-)

Comment: The term "delegate" can mean many things. In C# it means "an object that represents a function pointer". I'm not sure what it means to you.

Comment: When you say "I'd like to fire a method in classA", how do you expect classB to know which method in classA to call?

Comment: @Gabe, That's what I'm trying to figure out. How can I tell it what method to fire? And then how can I fire it?

Comment: Well, there are several ways classB may use to determine what method in classA to call. It could be told by classA. It could determine it based on the return value from the web service. It could simply be known at compile time. Each of those scenarios is completely different, so you have to tell us which one applies.

Answer (score 6):

A delegate is an object that points to a method, be it a static or instance method. So for your example, you would just use the event model:

```
class Caller {
    public void Call() {
        new Callee().DoSomething(this.Callback); // Pass in a delegate of this instance
    }

    public void Callback() {
        Console.WriteLine("Callback called!");
    }
}

class Callee {
    public void DoSomething(Action callback) {
        // Do stuff
        callback(); // Call the callback
    }
}

...

new Caller().Call(); // Callback called!
```

The `Caller` instance passes a delegate to the `Callee` instance's `DoSomething` method, which in turn calls the pointed-to method, which is the `Callback` method of the `Caller` instance.

Answer (score 5):

In C# what I think you are looking for are called events.  They are a language feature that allows a class instance to expose a public delegate in a way that other class instances can subscribe to.  Only the exposing class is allowed to raise the event.

In your example:

```
public class ClassB {
    // Note the syntax at the end here- the "(s, e) => { }" 
    // assigns a no-op listener so that you don't have to 
    // check the event for null before raising it.
    public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> MyEvent = (s, e) => { }

    public void DoMyWork() { 
        // Do whatever

        // Then notify listeners that the event was fired
        MyEvent(this, new MyEventArgs(myWorkResult));
    }
}

public class ClassA {
    public ClassA(ClassB worker) {
        // Attach to worker's event
        worker.MyEvent += MyEventHandler;

        // If you want to detach later, use
        // worker.MyEvent -= MyEventHandler;
    }

    void MyEventHandler(Object sender, MyEventArgs e) {
        // This will get fired when B's event is raised
    }
}

public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs {
    public String MyWorkResult { get; private set; }
    public MyEventArgs(String myWorkResult) { MyWorkResult = myWorkResult; }
}
```

Note that the above will be synchronous.  My understanding is that Objective-C delegates are all Actor pattern, so they are asynchronous.  To make the above asynch, you'll need to delve into threading (probably want to google "C# Thread pool").

Comment: I think OP needs A and B the opposite way ;) B is the child, B "calls" A method (so B raise the event, A suscribe to it)

Comment: Possibly- in that case I am giving him the benefit of the doubt that he can figure out how to reverse the pattern.